# why would a vbscript work on one computer but not another?

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-8

I was given the task of creating a macro in Macro Express using VBScript to copy data from one Internet Explorer-based platform and paste it to another IE-based platform. The code below worked perfectly on my computer. It also worked perfectly in a remote desktop environment. Some of the users that are testing it say it works fine. Others say it freezes up their computer and doesn't do anything. Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WShell, objShell, objShellWindows, objIE, URL, Window, URLFound, objOption
Dim Error, errormsg, intSpaceLoc, intParenLoc
Dim i, U, strName, strOutput, strFName, strLName, strEmployer, strMessage

On Error Resume Next
  Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then ShowError("It Failed")
On Error Goto 0

Claims_Search
Claims_Open
Modify_Search

Set WShell = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objShellWindows = Nothing
Set objIE = Nothing

'----------------------------

Sub ShowError(strMessage)

  WScript.Echo strMessage
  WScript.Echo "Error number: " & Err.Number & vbNewline & "Source: " & Err.Source & vbNewline & "Description: " & Err.Description
  Err.Clear

End Sub

'------------------------------

Sub Claims_Search()

  URL = "http://claims.url.com"
  U = Len(URL)
  Window = "Claim"

  Check_URL

End Sub

'-----------------------------

Function Check_URL()

  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  URLFound = False

  On Error Resume Next
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then ShowError("It Failed")
  On Error Goto 0

  For Each objIE In objShell.Windows
  Next

  For i = 0 To objShellWindows.Count - 1
    Set objIE = objShellWindows.Item(i)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Left(objShellWindows.Item(i).LocationURL, U) = (URL) Then
      If InStr(UCase(objShellWindows.Item(i).FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
          If InStr(objShellWindows.Item(i).Document.Title, (Window)) Then
            URLFound = True
            Exit For
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next

  If URLFound = False Then
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ErrorHandling
  End If

End Function

'------------------------------------

Function Claims_Open()

  objIE.Visible = True

  strName = objIE.Document.all.Item("ParticipantNameLink").innerText
  intSpaceLoc = InStr(strName, " ")
  strFName = Left(strName, intSpaceLoc)
  strLName = Replace(strName, strFName, "")
  strEmployer = objIE.Document.all.Item("Employer").innerText
  If InStr(strEmployer, "(") <> 0 Then
    intParenLoc = InStr(strEmployer, "(")
    strEmployer = Left(strEmployer, intParenLoc - 2)
  End If

  Wait_Webpage
  Exit Function

End Function

'-------------------------------

Sub Modify_Search()

  Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Window = "Non-Keyable Document Management System :: Modify Index"

  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

  For Each objIE In objShell.Windows
  Next

  For i = 0 To objShellWindows.Count - 1
    Set objIE = objShellWindows.Item(i)
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(UCase(objShellWindows.Item(i).FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
      If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If InStr(objShellWindows.Item(i).Document.Title, (Window)) Then
          Exit For
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next

  objIE.Visible = True

  Wait_Webpage

  objIE.Document.all.Item("txtLName").Value = strLName
  objIE.Document.all.Item("txtFName").Value = strFName
  objIE.Document.all.Item("txtCName").Value = strEmployer
  objIE.Document.all.Item("btn_submit").Click

End Sub

'--------------------------------

Sub ErrorHandling()

  WScript.Echo "EXIT"
  Err = MsgBox(ErrMsg, 48 + vbSystemModal, "ERROR")
  Set WShell = Nothing
  Set objShell = Nothing
  Set objShellWindows = Nothing
  Set objIE = Nothing
  WScript.Quit

End Sub

'----------------------------

Sub Wait_Webpage()

  While objIE.Busy = True
    WScript.sleep 200
  Wend

  While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
    WScript.sleep 200
  Wend

  While objIE.Document Is Nothing
    WScript.sleep 200
  Wend

End Sub
```

I hope someone can see what I can't. It makes no sense why this same code works for some and not for others.

Comment: If it works on some computers, but not on others, the problem is most likely with those other computers rather than the script.

Comment: I understand that it's likely the other computers, but is there something in the script that the computers it fails on may need to be able to work around? We are unable to check to see if scripting is enabled. They need a working solution that allows all computers to run it.

Comment: Sorry, but the cystal ball is at the cleaner's. You need a *lot* more than "doesn't work" for anyone to make an even halfway educated guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: Ok, may be grasping at straws, but would Internet Explorer (64-bit) versus Internet Explorer for opening new IE windows have something to do with it? I always use the 64-bit one because I've had issues with the regular one.

Comment: It might. As might a metric ton of other things.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in such cases of hanging there are concerns caused by interacting with created COM objects. Try to implement more failproof solutions.

Here is the example of waiting procedure:

```
Sub WaitIE(objIE, strId)
    With objIE
        ' wait until IE and the page are ready
        Do While .Busy Or Not .readyState = 4
            WScript.Sleep 10
        Loop
        ' wait until the DOM is ready
        Do Until .document.readyState = "complete"
            WScript.Sleep 10
        Loop
        ' wait until the target Id node is ready
        Do While TypeName(.document.getElementById(strId)) = "Null"
            WScript.Sleep 10
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Try to replace the numerous blocks of `objShellWindows` loops in your code with a function call, the code below is the example of `IEAttach()` function I adapted once from AutoIt for my needs:

```
Dim oIE
Set oIE = IEAttach(".com", "instance", "")
If oIE Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No matches"
Else
    MsgBox oIE.LocationName
End If

Function IEAttach(sString, sMode, iInstance)
    ' adapted from AutoIt https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEAttach.htm
    ' If sMode or iInstance is empty string "" or invalid - it will be considered as default
    ' sMode allows some of the AutoIt version: "title", "url", "text", "html", "hwnd", "instance"
    ' @error and @extended flags are not implemented, if no matches - Nothing will be returned
    Dim oDict, oWnd, oDocument
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set IEAttach = Nothing
    If Not IsNumeric(iInstance) Then iInstance = 1
    If iInstance < 1 Then iInstance = 1
    For Each oWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        Set oDocument = oWnd.Document
        If Instr(TypeName(oDocument), "HTML") Then
            Select Case LCase(sMode)
            Case "title"
                If Instr(oWnd.LocationName, sString) Then oDict.Add oDict.Count, oWnd
            Case "url"
                If Instr(oWnd.LocationURL, sString) Then oDict.Add oDict.Count, oWnd
            Case "text"
                If Instr(oDocument.body.innertext, sString) Then oDict.Add oDict.Count, oWnd
            Case "html"
                If Instr(oDocument.body.innerhtml, sString) Then oDict.Add oDict.Count, oWnd
            Case "hwnd"
                If oWnd.HWND = sString Then oDict.Add oDict.Count, oWnd
            Case "instance"
                oDict.Add oDict.Count, oWnd
            Case Else
                If Instr(oWnd.LocationName, sString) Then oDict.Add oDict.Count, oWnd
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    If oDict.Exists(iInstance - 1) Then Set IEAttach = oDict.Item(iInstance - 1)
End Function
```

You may loop this function call to be repeated until the necessary IE window is ready.